# How to implement binary search tree for a dictionary interface?

Tags: java, generics, dictionary, binary-search-tree

I'm given a Dictionary interface as follow:

```
public interface Dictionary<E extends Comparable<E>> extends Iterable<E> {
```

Now I'm asked to implement this interface using a binary search tree, however I don't know how to start since I'm quite confused with the theoretical concept of implementing the Dictionary interface above.

This is my implementing class:

```
// Red-black binary search tree
public class DictionaryImp implements Dictionary<DictionaryImp>, Comparable<DictionaryImp> {
```

So, how could I implement these following methods? What instance variables will be carried by the class DictionaryImp?

```
public boolean isEmpty();
public boolean contains(E item);
public boolean hasPredecessor(E item);
// etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your implementation of the red-black tree, but basically all your mentioned methods will call corresponding red-black tree methods.

isEmpty: check whether the tree is empty

contains(E item): perform a binary search on the tree to find the element. return true if it can be found

add(E item): if (!contains(item)) tree.add(item);

etc.etc.

Answer (score 0):

The class declaration you have doesn't make much sense. The type parameter of `Dictionary` seems to be for the element type of the dictionary; that's why they required the elements to be comparable to themselves. Your declaration seems to say that `DictionaryImp` is a dictionary whose elements are also `DictionaryImp`, which doesn't make sense. What you likely want is a `DictionaryImp` that is generic also, whose element type is comparable to itself, and implements dictionary with the same type parameter, like this:

```
public class DictionaryImp<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Dictionary<E>
```